Minimal greatest factor among factorizations into $5$ distinct factors.
The questions(from the IOQM 2020-2021 problem 14) states:

The product $55 \times 60 \times 65$ is written as the product of five distinct positive integers. What is the least possible value of the largest of these integers?

My thought process:
In a beautiful world, had repetition been allowed and the number would've been a perfect $5th$ power, I would write it as $n=n^{\frac{1}{5}}\cdot n^{\frac{1}{5}}\cdot n^{\frac{1}{5}}\cdot n^{\frac{1}{5}}\cdot n^{\frac{1}{5}}$ but that's not possible so the best we can do here is write it as the product of 1 digit numbers and 2 digits numbers.
I got $n=6 \cdot 10\cdot 11\cdot 13 \cdot 25$ so my answer was 25. This is not correct as we also have $n=5 \cdot 11\cdot 13\cdot 15 \cdot 20$ so answer is 20. I should have been more observant but still this question is very cumbersome. What if the number had been antiprime or had they asked to do the same by factorising it into 10 distinct postive integers? Are there any better solutions? Any ideas on how to tackle it and solve similar questions?
Thank you for your help. I am sorry if I sound bossy.

They have told distinct.

Things are not consistent: the only factor of $2$  comes from the $50,$   so the exponent on $2$  should be $1,$  and $20$ is not a divisor.  There is no factor of $3.$

So, my actual advice:  keep in mind the idea that you may be making mistakes. If you provide  a link to the source of the problem, we can decide whether the question  is faulty in some way.  For contest problems the original  language is not going to be a problem.

@WillJagy I am really really really sorry. I cannot believe I made such a mistake. $n=55\cdot60\cdot65$ Here is the official link https://olympiads.hbcse.tifr.res.in/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/IOQM-question-paper.pdf

This is a "bin-packing" problem. Those can be very hard.

" This is not correct as we also have n=5⋅11⋅13⋅15⋅20 so answer is 20."  but we also have $n = 10\cdot 11\cdot 13\cdot 15\cdot 10$.  You were close when you thought of $n^{\frac 15}$ but "the perfect is the enemy" of the good. We want the numbers to be as close to $(55\times 60\times 65)^{\frac 15}\approx 11.6$.  Your $11,13,15$ are "pretty close" but your $5,20$ can be made better by $10,10$.

@fleablood yes you have a point, but the question states the number should be written as a product of $5$ $distinct$ positive integers

Oh.... I didn't see that.  That puts a monkey wrench.  But I'd start with $10,11,13,15,10$ and realize we must adjust.  And one is to half and double a $10$ to get $5,11,13,15,20$.  But can we do better? Well, we don't want anything as large as $25$ so we need three distinct multiples of $5$.  If we dont want $20$ that leaves $5,10,15$ but we still have have prime components of $11,13$ and another $2$ to make two number less than $20$.  We just can't do better.

Call a factorisation of $n$ into $5$ distinct positive integer factors a good factorisation of $n$.
Lets denote the required minimal value of the largest factor in all of good factorisations of $n$, by $k$. We have $n=2^2\cdot 3\cdot 5^3\cdot 11\cdot 13$. This prime factorisation is indeed a good factorisation so $k\le 125$.
The key idea is that any factorisation of $n$ contains factors which are $1$ or are some product of any available prime factors of $n$. Further if we have a good factorisation of $n$ where highest factor is $r$ we get $k\leq r$;
from a given good factorisation the value of $k$ can be further improved only by decomposing $r$ into a new factor, ie replacing $r$ by a factor of itself, $r'$ and combining the lingering $\frac{r}{r'}$ with another factor. This is since combining or decomposing other factors just creates factors $<r$ or $\geq r$ which does not improve $k$.
Therefore we reduce $125$ to $25$ and a lingering $5$ in the prime factorisation of $n$*; one sees that if the lingering $5$ is combined to a low enough factor, a new minimal highest factor would be achieved, viz $25$. Thus, one combines $5$ with the factor $3$ to get $n= 4 \cdot 15 \cdot 25 \cdot 11 \cdot 13$ so $k\le 25$. Again a lower highest factor can only be achieved by reducing $25$ into $5$. Out of all possible ways of combining the factor of $5$, it is clear combining with $4$ leads to yet a newer minimal value: $20$. So one ends up with $n=20\cdot 15\cdot 13\cdot 11\cdot 5$. Thus $k\le 20$. Again, a further minimal value can be achieved by decomposing $20$ into $r$ and a lingering $r'$. If $r'\geq 4$ we have that combining $r'$ with any other factor would create factors $\geq 5r'= 20$; so $k$ is not improved. However if we decompose $20$ into $10$ and a lingering $2$ and combine it with $5$ we find a factorisation: $n= 10 \cdot 15 \cdot 13 \cdot 11 \cdot 10$. This factorisation is not good because of the repeated $10$ and from this factorisation to get rid of the repeated $10$ one would have to combine/decompose some factor which involves multiplying any of the factors by an integer $\geq 2$; so thus $k$ can't be improved further from here. Thus, $k=20$.
Here we essentially followed a greedy algorithm; where we reduce the maximal factor in such a way that the resulting new factorisation has a lower maximal element.
*: Instead of decomposing $125$ into $25$ and a lingering $5$, one could decompose it into $5$ and a lingering $25$ as well and ultimately get the same end-result with a lot more hardwork. However one can observe quite simply that a lingering $5$ can create factors all $\le 25$ while a lingering $25$ can at best create factors all $\le 75$. So the former is a better and quicker choice to arrive at the solution.
P.S.: You also ask in your body on the question what the result would be if we were asked to do the same exercise except where a good factorisation consists of $10$ distinct factors. Such a factorisation is infact impossible since $n=1\cdot 2\cdot2\cdot3\cdot5\cdot5\cdot5\cdot11\cdot13$.

Does greedy algo always work though? For example, how would you get from OP's attempt to the correct answer?

Sahaj, it turned out that the OP  screwed up the factorization. That is, $$  50 \cdot 55 \cdot 65  = 2 \cdot 5^4 \cdot 11 \cdot 13.$$ This is in comments below the question. The OP should have edited the question to include the correct factorization

@WillJagy as OP pointed in the comments and linked to, $n=55\cdot 60\cdot 65$. I believe it was incorrectly written as $50\cdot 55\cdot 65$ earlier.

@BenjaminWang this method is really just heuristic. The OP's attempt is not straightforward since when we combine $5$ with any other factor we can not achieve a better maximal. So instead we try to combine first some other factors which could allow us to lower the maximal element. Indeed, turning $6$ into $3$, combing the left $2$ with $10$ and then reducing the maximal $25$ into $5$ with the remaining element going to $3$ works.

Yes, it was  $50 \cdot 55 \cdot 65$  at first.

Two things.
The geometric average of the five numbers is $\sqrt[5]{55\times 50\times 65}\approx 11.6$ so to have the smallest highest number we should have each number be as close to that as possible.
The prime components of $55\times 60\times 65$ are $2,2,3,5,5,5,11,13$.  To get the five numbers as close to $11.6$ as possible we shouldn't combine the $11$ or $13$ with any other components and they are as close as possible as they are.  It's now obvious that two of the $5$s can combine with the to $2$s to get $10$ and $10$ and the third $5$ can combine with the $3$ to get $15$ and your five numbers are $10,10,11,13,15$ with a highest of $15$.
But even if that weren't "obvious" we have eight prime components which must be distributed into five "slots" to make the five numbers.  By pigeon hole principal we must have at least two numbers consist of at most one component.  To get get the five numbers to have the smallest largest number, these two numbers that have at most one prime component should be the largest prime components $11$ and $13$. (If either were to consist of smaller prime components, or were to be equal to $1$, then the remaining three numbers would consist of higher remaining components and thus average to three higher numbers and we'd have a higher largest number.)
So two of our numbers should be $11$ and $13$ and what remains is to distribute $2,2,3,5,5,5$ and what remains is two distribute these six components to three slots. If we assume there two components to each number to keep these as close to the average, we should combine the largest, $5$, with the smallest, $2$ and then the second largest, $5$, with the second smallest and so on to get $2\times 5=10, 2\times 5= 10, 3\times 5 = 15$.
But if we don't distribute two components to a number then by Pigeon hole we will have at least one number with at most one component and another with at least three.  The number with at most one component, as we argued above, should be the largest component, $5$.  The number with at least $3$ components will need to have a component that isn't $5$.  So if we have $5$ and a second number $a\times b \times c$ with $2\le a=\min(a,b,c)<5$ we can make redistribute the $a$ to get $b\times c$ and $5\times a$. As $b\times c < a\times b \times c$, the only way this can be less efficient is if $5\times a$ is now larger than what $a\times b\times c$ was originally.
The only way that $5a > a\times b\times c$ is if $5\ge b\times c$ and that can only be if $b=c=2$.  But the $a > 2$ contridicting we could distribute the minimum of $a,b,c$.

OR... if we are willing to make leaps of faith we can to a  tl;dr version.
However we distribute the $2,2,3,5,5,5,11,13$ to five numbers if we combine either the $11$ and $13$ with any other we get a number that just seems too large. (We want them close to $11.6$ and $22$ is just too big.
To distribute the remaining $6$ components to the remaining $3$ numbers we don't want to combine a $5$ with a $5$ because that's $25$ and that's just too big.
So we must distrubite the $5$s to three different numbers.  $5d, 5e, 5f$ where $d,e,f$ are combinations of $2,2,3,$ and an indefinate number of $1$s. As $d\times e\times f = 2\times 2\times 3$ they average to $\sqrt[3]{12}\approx 2.2$ the best way to distribute them is $2,2,3$ so are five numbers are $2\times 5=10, 2\times 5=10, 3\times 5=10, 11,13$
